# dBase command to replace a character with a newline

Tags: foxpro, dbase

I use a museum/archival software program called PastPerfect. This program has a "Global Update" search and replace function with limited functionality and also a "Command Window" that you can access from that screen that it says "will accept commands in the dBase language" to make global changes to my records.

I have a number of records that I imported into PastPerfect from another source that are formatted such that when a field has multiple entries it uses a vertical bar as a divider, (So, for example, the subject term memo field for a book might contain "New Hampshire--History|Washington, Mount (N.H.)--History"), when multiple entries are supposed to be separated with a carriage return. (The memo field should read:

New Hampshire--History

Washington, Mount (N.H.)--History

So what I need is to do a global update to replace all of the vertical bars with a carriage return. This would be easy to do with Microsoft Words find and replace function, but the PastPerfect Global Update menu does not allow me to replace with any special characters.

So is there a dBase function that will allow me to search the field for the "|" symbol and replace it with a newline/carriage return character. I have been Googling but cannot find anything to get me started for the life of me. It looks as though the REPLACE function replaces the entire field (rather than just searching for a string of characters).

Alternatively, if anyone knows of a program for manipulating DBF files that DOES have a powerful enough find and replace function to be able to replace with newline characters, I may be able to export these records out in dBase format and reimport them. I have tested a few programs but all the ones I have found so far only have simple find and replace functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the "Command Windows" is within VFP, you should be good to go and it easy.  I don't know the name of the table, nor the actual column, but it should be as simple as...

```
update YourTable;
   set YourColumn = strtran( YourColumn, "|", chr(13)+chr(10))
```

and EVERY row that has the pipe character will be converted to a cr/lf... even if its one or many instances. You might need to offer a little more about the table, let me know and I'll adjust.

As for using the REPLACE command, that too would work with the STRTRAN() call.

```
USE YourTable
REPLACE ALL YourColumn WITH strtran( YourColumn, "|", chr(13)+chr(10))
```

This too will update ALL rows.  And if there is no pipe "|" character, the memo field will be left as-is/unchanged.

Comment: I used the first command you provided and it worked like a charm. Thanks, so much!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, we want change the letter (a) to "c" what ever the position of "a".

Try the following code:

```
{nn="a"}

{USE your_table}

{GO top}

   {DO whil NOT EOF()}

  { aa=LEN(ALLTRIM(field_name))}

 {  aa1=ALLTRIM(field_name)}

{   new_value=""}

 {  FOR ii=1 TO aa}

 {  v=SUBSTR(aa1,ii,1)}

 {  IF v=nn}

{   v="c"}

  { ENDIF}

 {  new_value=new_value+v}

 {  ENDFOR}

 {  REPLACE field_name WITH new_value}

  { SKIP}

 {  ENDDO}

 {  close data}
```

Comment: wow... sorry, but look into other string functions.  STRTRAN() does it for you...  CHRTRAN() is another very nice function.

Comment: Also what's with the braces?